# How can I detect and catch the allow-popups event inside an iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Please see the following code, basically I have the following:

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d6hd8u

HTML: `app.component.html`

```
<h1>YouTube Test</h1>
<iframe 
  sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vN-96ej5SgQ"
  width="500px"
  height="350px">
  </iframe>

<h1>Catching iFrame Events</h1>
<p>{{ event_status | json }}</p>
```

TS: `app.component.ts`

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  event_status = "Waiting for event to fire ...";

  @HostListener('window:message', ['$event'])
  updateStatus(event) {
    this.event_status = "Triggered ...";
    var mainWindow = event.source;
    var result = '';
    try {
      result = eval(event.data);
    } catch (e) {
      result = 'eval() threw an exception.';
    }
    mainWindow.postMessage(result, event.origin);    
    this.event_status = result;
  }
```

I'm trying to "catch" / "Listen" to the event when you click the YouTube's title ( for example ) - it opens a `popup` which I allow via `<iframe sandbox="... allow-popups">` but I can't seems to catch it ...

The overall idea is so I can the ask the user - if he really wants to go to YouTube - or cancel ...

Any thoughts ?

Comment: You can't access inside cross domain iframes and events in iframe window do not bubble to parent window. Perhaps the youtube js api has methods you can use

Comment: I thought that maybe I can catch the event from the `iframe`->`sandbox` -> `allow-popups`' event ...because YouTube didn't even kicked in yet ... it will open in a new window ....
But I've seen apps that do that, and also Apple requested me to do that - so I guess there's a solution for it :/